# Swift Changing the size of tableview cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell

just like the title says I'm searching for a way to change the size of each cell in my tableview. I have 2 questions:

1) How can I change the size of all cells by the same amount in my tableview?

2) Is it possible to automatically adjust the size of the cell based on the length of the text in that particular cell?

I'm aware that there are already similar questions asked before but I couldn't manage to implement their answers correctly as they've been outdated for some time now. I'd appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To change size of all cells with same type, first you need to create `CellType`, here is the explanation how to do this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51979506/8417137
or you can check for indexPath.row, but it's not cool :)

Than here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch cellType {
    case firstType:
      return firstCellTypeHeight
    case secondType: 
      return secondCellTypeHeight
    default:
      return defaultCellHeight
    }
}
```

2) Yes, its possible. You create your `CustomCell`. In your `CustomCell` you should 
setup your textFields or labels inside `ContentView`. Your views with text will stretch your cell.

Important thing. In method above you must return special height like that.

```
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

For example your code will looks like that.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch cellType {
    case firstType:
      return firstCellTypeHeight
    case secondType: 
      return secondCellTypeHeight
    // Your stretching cell
    case textCellType:
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch cellType {
    case firstType:
      return firstCellTypeHeight
    case secondType: 
      return secondCellTypeHeight
    // Your stretching cell
    case textCellType:
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without creating a new file? How can I use the indexPath.row method to change the sizes?? Thanks for the detailed answer also!

Comment: If you know for true what type of cell you have. To not create another answer I give you this link with screenshot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dly1k9ixlrzxq1n/Screenshot%202018-08-26%2000.38.24.png?dl=0

Comment: alright I used the function in the screenshot, the cell enlarged but still, the text is not fully visible. Here is how a single cell looks like https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzxbrgxgt8yg3o2/Screen%20Shot%202018-08-25%20at%209.49.35%20PM.png?dl=0  Sorry for taking your time I just want to fix this issue :-(

Comment: you should setup your textLabel "textLabel.numberOfLines = 0"

Comment: Glad I could help you! :)